# Accessing Oracle Wallet using Oracle sqlplus Instant client

Tags: linux, oracle, sqlplus, instantclient

I've configured Oracle wallet successfully in my Linux server(Linux 2.6.32-642.4.2.el6.x86_64 GNU/Linux).

**When I try to execute the below command using Database connection string, it works perfect.**

$/sqlplus /@TESTDB

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Tue Oct 18 07:12:49 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning option

SQL>

**But, when I run the same command using sqlplus Instant Client, it's throwing the below error. Please help me to resolve this.**

$ oracle/instantclient/11.1.0.6.0-ml01/.exec/x86-64.linux.2.6/bin/sqlplus /@TESTDB

SQL*Plus: Release 11.1.0.6.0 - Production on Tue Oct 18 07:14:38 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2007, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12534: TNS:operation not supported

**Note:
Any way, When I use the Instant sqlplus client to connect using username and password, it works fine.**

/oracle/instantclient/11.1.0.6.0-ml01/.exec/x86-64.linux.2.6/bin/sqlplus USERNAME/PASSWORD@TESTDB

SQL*Plus: Release 11.1.0.6.0 - Production on Tue Oct 18 07:16:46 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2007, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning option

SQL>

Comment: Is this any help? http://www.orafaq.com/forum/mv/msg/181952/557475/#msg_557475

Comment: Hi bassrek, It did not solve my problem. I did the same setup as mentioned. It works perfectly with standard sqlplus, but with Instant sqlplus it fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to recreate the wallet using the specific environment. For example, my oracle-11 client wallet doesn't work when I have an oracle-12 environment defined ... and vice versa. Neither of my client configs are instant clients, but I think the 'secure external password' (aka wallet) store is specific to the client.